# How to avoid inspection warning when call a static method of a variable class name in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

When I call something like:

```php
$class_name = '\App\Models\User';
$class_name::create($attributes);
```

PhpStorm shows an inspection warning "Method 'create' not found in string".

I don't want to switch off this inspection, as it's very useful in other cases. Is there another way to avoid the warning, using annotations or something else?

Comment: You may help IDE by adding a `@var` PHPDoc annotation above the variable usage.
In this case, it will look like `/** @var $class_name \App\Models\User  */`

Comment: Perhaps try `class-string` type from Psalm? https://psalm.dev/docs/annotating_code/type_syntax/scalar_types/#class-string-interface-string You need to have that plugin enabled in PhpStorm (it is enabled by default). You do not need the actual Psalm tool.

Answer (score 1):

The warning you're seeing in PhpStorm is likely due to the fact that PhpStorm is statically analyzing the code, and when you use a string to represent a class name, PhpStorm can't infer the actual class and, therefore, doesn't recognize the methods associated with that class.

To mitigate this, you can use PHPDoc annotations:

```php
/** @var \App\Models\User $class */
$class = '\App\Models\User';

$class::create($attributes);
```

Comment: That actually works, though I'm getting another problem: as I have the $class as another class property, which I declare as string, it gives a weak warning 'Property type does not match'. This can be solved if I use string|User type, but this would be incorrect to use, as I don't want the User model to be able to pass into this class

Comment: If you want to avoid using string|User type for the property, you can try using the class-string type hint specifically for the property. This indicates that the property should hold a string representing a class name. 

class YourClass {
    /** @var class-string */
    private $class;

}

Is that something you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I've found another way, maybe someone will use it:

```
call_user_func($class . '::create', $attributes);
```

Not ideal, but works fine